# Is there a way to make the Kafka consumer poll-function throw errors, rather than the library handling them internally?

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka

I'm working on a Kafka consumer in kotlin/javalin, using the standard kafka library `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer`, and struggling a bit with the poll function, as it seems to never throw any errors that can be caught, it just writes warn/errors to the console. For example, when it's not able to reach the broker, it logges a warning that "Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.":

```
{
  "timestamp": "2022-12-14T13:30:58.673+01:00",
  "level": "WARN",
  "thread": "main",
  "logger": "org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient",
  "message": "[Consumer clientId=xxx, groupId=xxx] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:1000) could not be established. Broker may not be available."
}
```

But it doesn't actually throw any errors, so it's pretty much impossible to handle the error, if you would like to do anything other than just continue to poll forever. Does anyone know if there is some way to configure this behavior? Or am I missing something?

The relevant code

```
consumer = createConsumer() // This returns a Consumer<String?, String?>
consumer.subscribe(listOf(TOPIC))

while (true) {
    val records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
    records.iterator().forEach {
        println(it.key())
    }
    consumer.commitSync() // Commit offset after finished processing entries
}
```

I can trigger a timeout-error if I call the `partitionsFor`-function from the consumer, so this can work as a liveness-probe, but this feels more like a hack than the intended way to do it.

```
try {
    var committed = consumer.partitionsFor(TOPIC)
} catch (e: Exception) {
    println(e)
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The client is dumb, and expects you to provide the correct values.

You can use `AdminClient.describeCluster()` with the same address to verify connection, then catch/throw RuntimeException from that.

Otherwise, the consumer will retry and update the metadata for your `bootstrap.servers` until it can connect.